# Watson Classifier curl authentication failing with userid and password

Tags: ibm-watson, nl-classifier

I followed the instructions and retrieved the credentials for https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-classifier/api - from the resource list I was able to retrieve my Username and Password.  I have a trained classifier that I can use with Watson Studio.  The classifier I retrieved from the Watson Services page for my project is: befb8ax501-nlc-1441.  I then try to test out a simple test -
curl -u "{userid}":"{password}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-classifier/api/v1/classifiers/befb8ax501-nlc-1441" and I receive {"code":401, "error": "Unauthorized"}
This seems very basic and simple, but I can't seem to get this to work.  I am using curl because the python program I wrote (which worked a few months ago with a different password and service id) doesn't seem to be working.
I can perform operations with the web interface so the service is working - but I can't seem to call it.  Is there a way I can test my username and password?  Am I using the correct format to make the call?

Answer (score 0):

Open your classifier and then click on your service.
[image]

This will open service page, then go under service credentials, now if you see key like "apsx-data". Now thats the service credentials that the watson studio test screen uses.
[image]

If you click apsx-data, it will expand, you can use the credential.
If this credential, doesn't try to create new credential and try using that.
If this still doesn't work, you should open a ticket since it may be specific to your service.